# Watch OS: Creating a Circular Progress Bar

Tags: swift, animation, progress-bar, watchkit

Is there a way to create an animated circular progress bar on the Watch? 
[image: Circular Loader]

I don't want to use multiple loading images to create this effect. Maybe using a Game Scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Used an SKScene. Created a circular path using UIBezierPath. And attached it to an SKShapeNode. Finally, animated the path using an SKAction.

Hope this helps someone.

```swift
class RestScene: SKScene {


    override func sceneDidLoad() {


        addCircle()
    }


    func addCircle() {

        let path = getCirclePath(ofRadius: 50, withPercent: 1)

        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: path)
        shapeNode.strokeColor = .blue
        shapeNode.fillColor = .clear
        shapeNode.lineWidth = 4
        shapeNode.lineCap = .round
        shapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        shapeNode.zRotation =  CGFloat.pi * 0.5

        self.addChild(shapeNode)


        animateStrokeEnd(circle: shapeNode, duration: 5){
            shapeNode.path = nil
            print("Done")
        }
    }

    func getCirclePath(ofRadius radius :CGFloat, withPercent percent:CGFloat) -> CGPath {
       return  UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero,
                     radius: radius,
                     startAngle: 0,
                     endAngle: 2 * .pi * percent,
                     clockwise: true).cgPath



    }

    func animateStrokeEnd(circle:SKShapeNode, duration:TimeInterval, completion:@escaping ()->Void)  {
        guard let path = circle.path else {
            return
        }
        let radius = path.boundingBox.width/2
        let animationAction = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: duration) { (node, elpasedTime) in
            let percent =  elpasedTime/CGFloat(duration)
            (node as! SKShapeNode).path = self.getCirclePath(ofRadius: radius, withPercent: 1 - percent)
        }

        circle.run(animationAction) {
            completion()
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: had to set the position to half width and half height to make it positioned at the center of the watch screen

Answer (score -2):

Hi @aledap you can use third party library for achieving this. Add this library in your pod file.

[See this library this will helps you](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView)

circleStrokeSpin is the loader you want is present in it have a look.

Happy Coding

Comment: I don't think this will help me, this is an animation. I want to run a timer increase fill of circle path accordingly.